# Как продолжить действие скрипта после его остановки?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет у меня на сайте есть полоса загрузки, я использую `ontouchstart` чтобы при нажатии на экран (пальцем или мышкой) загрузка приостановилась `jQuery(".skillbar").stop();`
и я хочу чтобы при отпускании экрана `ontouchend` полоса загрузки продолжила свою работу с того места где остановилась

Есть такой код, но он не до конца работает (останавливает, но не продолжает)

```
<div class="storiestime">
      <div class="skills" data-percent="100%" id="skills" style="transition: 1s;">
            <div class="skillbar"></div>  
    </div>
 </div>

<script>
    let elapsedTime = 0;
    let startTime;
    let storyTime = 15000;
     $('.zerostories').click(function(){ 
      startAnimation();
     function startAnimation(){
      jQuery('.skills').each(function(){
        var skillBar = jQuery(this).find('.skillbar');
          skillBar.animate({
              width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
          }, {
              duration: storyTime,
              start: function(anim) {
                  startTime = new Date();
              },
              always: function(anim, jumpedToEnd) {
                  let endTime = new Date();
                  elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
              }
          });
     });
 }
});
    $(".closestoris").on("click", function() {
        $('.likeproductstories').hide();
        $("#imagelike").attr("src","img/likestory.png");
        $("#dataModal").modal("hide");
        var skillBar = $(".skillbar");
        skillBar.stop();
        elapsedTime = 0;
        skillBar.width(0);
    });

function myFunction() {
jQuery(".skillbar").stop();

}

function myFunctiontwo() {
  var skillBar = jQuery(this).find('.skillbar');
    console.log("StoryTime: " + storyTime + " ElapsTime: " + elapsedTime);
  skillBar.animate({
          width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
        }, storyTime - elapsedTime, function() {
            $("#dataModal").modal("hide");
            skillBar.width(0);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто вычисляйте/модифицируйте оставшееся для анимации время:

```
duration: timeTotal - timeLeft,
```

```js
const bar = $('.bar');
const startBtn = $('.start');
const stopBtn = $('.stop');
const resetBtn = $('.reset');
let totalTime = 5000;

startBtn.on('click', function() {
  bar.animate({
    width: bar.data('percent'),
  }, {
    duration: totalTime - (bar.timeLeft|0),
    start: () => bar.startTime = Date.now(),
    always: () => bar.timeLeft = Date.now() - bar.startTime,     
  });
});

stopBtn.on('click', () => bar.stop());

resetBtn.on('click', () => {
  bar.stop();
  bar.timeLeft = 0;
  bar.css({width: '0%'});
});
```

```css
.bar {
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bar" data-percent="100%"></div>
 <hr/ >
 <button class="start">Start</button>
 <button class="stop">Stop</button>
 <button class="reset">Reset</button>
```